# Problemas con PyInstaller y webbrowser en ejecutable Python

Tags: python, navegador-web, pyinstaller

Tengo una aplicación simple realizada con Qt y Python. He utilizado webbrowser para abrir el navegador web por defecto y mostrar una imagen mediante una url. La función se llama mediante el siguiente comando:

`webbrowser.open_new(url)`

Cuando lo ejecuto en modo de desarrollo funciona bien. Sin embargo, cuando se compila la aplicación usando PyInstaller y se ejecuta como un ejecutable me aparece este mensaje:

> gio: (url) Error opening location: No application is registered as handling this file

He probado a utilizar otras funciones de webbrowser para abrir urls añadiendo parametros de configuración y sigue sin funcionar.

Hago mención a otro problema similar, el cual no tiene respuestas ni solución. [pyinstaller: webbrowser.open doesn't work in packaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657864/pyinstaller-webbrowser-open-doesnt-work-in-packaged-app)

Comment: Es importante que indiques la versión de sistema operativo y la del navegador que estás probando. El error `gio` indica que estás intentando abrir la url con GTK, probablemente con `gvfs-open` en gnome3 o puede que con `xdg-open` si empleas Qt. Siempre puedes forzar el uso de un navegador registrándolo con `webbrowser.register` (mírate el el fichero `webbrowser.py` en tu instalación para ver cómo se hace).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. La versión del sistema operativo es Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS y el navegador es Chrome 76.0.3809.132 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Comment: Como te decía, `xdg-open` no funciona correctamente cuando creas el empaquetado. Seguramente no sea capaz de leer el fichero con los tipos mimes o algo similar. Siento no poder concretar más. La estrategia es forzar el navegador que quieres usar en lugar de intentar usar el que esté definido por defecto. Mírate la documentación de [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html).

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias. Tan solo hay que asignarle un navegador en concreto mediante la funcion .get de webbrowser.